# How can I most easily correct form calculations after updating a case property via a form edit?

Tags: commcare

Situation: an initial form that dictates a case property relevant for a visit with a participant was completed incorrectly. We have edited the form submitted to properly correct the input and update the case property. However, this case property is used in hidden calculations in about 15 follow-up forms in the same visit.

What is the best way to go about correcting the incorrect case property use in these follow-up forms that have already been submitted? I have tried opening a form via edit form submission and then resaving it, but the calculation using the case property maintained the incorrect property that was used in the original form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Changing form data is a tough thing to do in CommCare. Here are a couple recommendations

#### Edit submissions

When the form is loaded, it will use the most current version of that case to do hidden calculations. I'm surprised to see that the form did not recompute the hidden calculation, I would double check to make sure that the case has the value you expect when you load the form.

#### Archiving forms

In some cases it's easiest to archive the form and resubmit it. This doesn't work too well when there are complex case manipulations happening (which seems to be your case)

---

In general CommCare has the philosophy that form data is not editable and that anything that needs to be in any way mutable should be stored in a case.